# How to parametrise $x^2 + y^2 = z^2; z \in [0, 1]$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric

How to parametrise $x^2 + y^2 = z^2; z \in [0, 1]$?

I want to parametrise so I can use the divergence theorem to calculate the flux along the surface above.

I don't know how to do it and would like some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each fixed value of $z$, you have a circle of radius $|z|$ on $x$ and $y$. So, as $z\in[0,1]$, you can parametrize
$$
x=z\,\cos t\,\ \ y=z\,\sin t,\ \ z\in[0,1],\ t\in[0,2\pi).
$$

If you want to parametrize the volume inside the surface, you can use the same idea to parametrize
$$
x=r\,\cos t\,\ \ y=r\,\sin t,\ \ 0\leq r\leq z,\ \ z\in[0,1],\ t\in[0,2\pi).
$$

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: My pleasure. ${ }$

Comment: How would I write $dV$ now for my integral? What is it equal to now I have changed from cartesian to polar?

Comment: When you calculate a flux there is no "cartesian" or "polar". You integrate over a parametrization of your surface.

Comment: But I am using Divergence theorem so I need to evaluate $$\iiint_V 2+x~dV$$ obviously I can use your parameterisation for $x$ but what do I do with $dV$ in order to evaluate?

Comment: In that case you don't want to parametrize the surface; you want to parametrize the volume inside.

Comment: How would I do that? Similar to this but let the magnitude of the circles go from zero to z?

Comment: Yes. Please see the edit.

Comment: So I go back to my first question now, what would $dV$ become in the triple integral?

Comment: With the parametrization in the answer, $dV=r\,drdtdz$.

Comment: Is that the result of using the Jacobian then, same for when $dA \rightarrow rdrd\theta$?

Comment: Yes.${ \ \ \ \ }$

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 1-1 parameter inaction, you can take your domain the closed unit disk and define $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.

Comment: I think this will be harder when dealing with the volume integral following.